# Can someone explain what the '$' means in this command line example?

Tags: linux, jenkins

This script is located towards the bottom of this page http://jenkins-php.org/ under "Using the Job Template" heading.

```
cd $JENKINS_HOME/jobs
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-jenkins-template.git php-template
chown -R jenkins:nogroup php-template/
```

I am just confused what the '$' means in the first line before JENKINS_HOME. I have never seen a dollar sign used like that and have not yet found an explanation for it using Google searches. Thanks.

Comment: It is an environment variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means the value stored in the variable named JENKINS_HOME.

This command

```
echo $JENKINS_HOME
```

will display the value stored in this variable.

[This link](http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-script-variables.html) provides a brief intro/summary about the use of shell variables. Basically one assigns to a variable without the `$`, but in order to get to its value, it's necessary to put the `$` in front of the variable one is interested in.

Comment: Cool I see what is going on here. I want to accept your answer but it's telling me I have to wait 13 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

It means it is a variable, often used for environmental variables such as $PATH, $USER, and $HOME.

Answer (score 1):

Just like in PHP, a $ denotes a variable in unix/linux shell scripts. This includes environment variables. In a Windows batch script, you would use `%JENKINS_HOME%`

Answer (score 1):

It is probably an [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Unix) that (probably) contains the path to jenkins installation. To check the value of the variable, just type this on the command prompt:

```
echo $JENKINS_HOME
```